# Difference between from nltk import word_tokenize and from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize?

Tags: nlp, nltk

What is the difference between the word_tokenize, one imported directly from nltk and the other being imported from tokenize package of nltk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically

[`from nltk import word_tokenize`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.sonority_sequencing.SyllableTokenizer)

and

[`from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize)

`from nltk import word_tokenize` is basing to the same tokenizeAPI as both are the same with the usage and I don't see any difference in the results which they give.